# In One Piece, what happened to Crocodile after Luffy beat him?

Tags: one-piece

I heard that Crocodile was sent to Impel down after he was knocked out by Luffy's Gomu Gomu no Pistol, but what happened to him? Did he ever escape or does he even get executed alongside Doflamingo & Arlong? And how did they find him in the floor?

Comment: Hi Dudu, I think you got the timeline a little bit too mixed up here by bringing Arlong and Doflamingo together. Because Arlong was before the Arabasta arc and Doflamingo in Dressrosa arc. Arabasta arc and Dressrosa are.. hundreds of chapters/episodes apart but i'll try to answer your question..

Comment: Doflamingo has not been executed but imprisoned in Impel Down (as of Chapter 940, I haven't read further).

Answer (score 2):

I will answer this in chronological order:

- I don't recall they ever mentioned that Arlong was executed, the last thing we know about Arlong was that he got captured by the Marines.
- There wasn't any explanation on how the Marines picked Crocodile from under the rubble, the only thing they mentioned was that Crocodile was captured by Captain Tashigi (the sword lady serving under Vice Admiral Smoker), Crocodile was sent to Impel Down and his Sichibukai (Seven Warlord of the sea) rank was stripped.

***SPOILER ALERT***

- We will see Crocodile appearance in Impel Down arc, right before Marineford arc or the Paramount war arc. I will not tell you the details but all i can say Crocodile and many others teamed up with Luffy.
- As for Doflamingo i know for sure after the Dressrosa arc that he was just arrested by Admiral Fujitora and locked up at Impel Down later on. Also got his Sichibukai rank stripped.

I hope this answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

After escaping from Impel Down with Luffy and fighting through Marineford, Crocodile goes to the New World with Daz Bones. He get enough money to give Buggy a large loan for his delivery service/piracy scheme. When Crocodile wanted to get paid back, he took over Buggys Delivery Service, him and Hawkeye Mihawk "work under" Buggy the Clown to put bounties on Marines, so Buggy gets all the infamy, when Croc and Hawk just take in the power and money.

Answer (score -1):

The final attack on Crocodile is called gomu gomu no storm. Gomu gomu no pistol is a normal punch, in gomu gomu no storm Luffy kick Crocodile into the air then do Gomu gomu no ballon to inflates his belly and twist his body, then propel himself into the airs and untwist and use this propulsion to punch Crocodile with a lot of punches akin to gomu gomu no Gatling.

Crocodile don´t get trapped in rubble, Luffy attack punches out Crocodile out of the catacomb and right into the ground right next to the battle between the rebels and the royal guard.

Tashigi stripes Crocodile of the Sichibukai title and the Marine detains him.

He goes to a no named prison with the rest of with Mr 1, Mr 4, Miss Double finger and Miss Chrismas.

Miss Goldenweek helps with Mr 2, Mr 5 and Miss Valentine rescue Mr 4, Miss Double Finger and Miss Chrismas but Crocodile and Mr 1 did´t want to be rescued.

With Mr 2 that sacrifices himself and Mr 3 that are captured, the four of the goes to Impel Down, an underwater prison located in Calm Belt, between Marineford, the Marine Headquarters and Ennies Lobby, the judicial island. These three island are connected with the Tarai current, a whirlpool that the Marine can ride to travel faster between these locations.